# Difference in differences with unequal periods?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, causality, difference-in-difference

In the typical difference-in-differ
rences design with multiple time periods the periods concerned are equal e.g. days, months, years.

What, if any, are the implications of having time periods of different duration e.g. $t_1$ ~ 5 days, $t_2$ ~ 10 days, $t_3$ ~ 1 day etc?

For instance, say we have data of the following form, concerning voting in a single election in which ballots can be submitted on any one day over the study period:

| ID | Voted | CampaignStartDate | CampaignExp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 02-Jan-2019 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 05-Jan-2019 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 10-Jan-2019 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 20-Jan-2019 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 02-Jan-2019 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 05-Jan-2019 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 10-Jan-2019 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 20-Jan-2019 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

`ID` indexes voters, `Voted` indicates whether the voter has submitted their ballot between `CampaignStartDate` and the day before the next `CampaignStartDate`, and `CampaignExp` indicates whether the voter was exposed (daily) to a campaign that ran from `CampaignStartDate` up to (depending on the campaign) the end of the study period or earlier.

Given this setup, and provided that we have data on the same individuals from a recent pre-treatment election that the campaigns were not run, would it make sense to estimate:

$Voted_{it} = \alpha_{i} + \lambda_{t} + \beta CampaignExp_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$

Where $t$ indexes the pre-treatment period and the periods in between campaign start dates?

Comment: Would you mind please offering a specific example and describing what you intend to prove.

Comment: Technically, the “canonical” approach involves two periods (i.e., before versus after). Once we move to a setting with more than two time periods, there is no requirement that the epochs be balanced, though more pre-periods allows you to demonstrate a commonality of the trends between treatment/control groups as the intervention nears. Can you tell us what $t_1$, $t_2$, and $t_3$ mean? Is $t_3$ a new treatment, or is it a period where the treatment is removed? Please be as precise as possible.

Comment: Edited with an example